# How to update models with hashes without conversion of integers to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I often build hashes in my controllers which I used to update models, and just ran into an issue when using integers for keys.  Ruby will convert integer keys into strings, but not for integers in arrays I use as values.  Is there a way to ensure that Ruby maintains the keys as integers?

Example:

```
team_attribute = {"teams"=>{1=>["tom",3,"rob"],2=>[5,"bill","jim"]}}
@model.update(team_attribute)
```

Will end up

```
@model.teams
{"1"=>["tom",3,"rob"],"2"=>[5,"bill","jim"]}
```

While I can deal with the keys as strings with some work-arounds, I want the keys integers for loop simplicity later on. Thanks.

Edit: The datatype is JSONB, and 'team' is an attribute of @model in this example.

Comment: What data type is `teams` I am assuming `JSON` which would explain the conversion because `JSON` keys are `String`s ?

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated my Q, it is JSONB.  Is this just a native 'feature' of JSON that I will need to work around?

Comment: Yes json keys must be strings